# Creating fixed buffer around a selected point in QGIS version 2.18.2

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am relatively new to QGIS. I recently downloaded the version 2.18.2 and a lot of the geoprocessing tool options I was used to in the previous version seem to be gone. I want to create a buffer around one **selected** point in a vector layer, but the "Use Selected Features" option is no longer there (see below). Any suggestions? [image]

Comment: It will be applied on selected points. Just select the points and internally the selected points will be buffered

Comment: I guess you don't want circles of 10 degrees arund you points? You better reproject to a CRS that uses meters as units.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this question was asked before but can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go to

```
Processing > Options... > General
```

And check the `Use only selected features` option.

[image: Option]

Answer (score 3):

Just select the points and internally the selected points will be buffered.

[image]

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Only the selected features will be buffered.

If nothing is selected everything is buffered.

This changed in QGIS 2.18 where processing is now used for the vector tools, so the FWtools was removed: http://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/geoprocessing-qgis-2-14-vs-2-16